# table of values and definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f$ be a function with $f(0) = 9$, $f(4) = 7$, and $f '(4) = 3$.
 Evaluate the integral $$\int_{0}^{4}xf''(x)dx$$

I tried to solve it using a method my teacher showed to us in class but it involved a huge table of values. I feel like there is missing information.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Use integration by parts to get $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{4}xf''(x)\,dx = \left[xf'(x)\right]_{0}^{4} - \int_{0}^{4}f'(x)\,dx$.

Evaluating $xf'(x)$ at $x = 0$ and $x = 4$ is doable from the data you are given.

Also, $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{4}f'(x)\,dx$ should be fairly simple to integrate.